# AND function and conditional formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

When attempting to conditionally format rows using the formula below
=AND($A2>=$B2, $B2<>"")

I get the error captured in the screenshot. Column A and column B are dates.
The purpose for the second condition $B2<>"" is to ensure that Excel does not apply formatting to rows where the date field in column B is blank.

[image]

Any pointer to how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Edited: 11:35 AM PT to add the screenshot of conditional formula

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me, Can you maybe screencap the condition?

Comment: Thank you reviewing this. I have a simplified example screenshot added to the original post

Comment: Again, works fine for me. Are you sure those are all dates and not text that looks like a date? What happens if you put the formula in a cell for the problem rows?

Answer (score 0):

The error message occurred because the List Separator on Excel settings was set to a pipe ("|") by me. I modified it back to comma and this issue was resolved.
To change the List Separator:

Control Panel --> Region --> Change date, time, or number formats, click the Additional settings... button then look for List separator under the Numbers tab.

I had modified this for generating CSV file with a pipe separator.